# How to Get the True Count in Boolean Array in Kotlin

Tags: java, kotlin

I've read the kotlin documentation and tried `BooleanArray.count(predicate: (Boolean) -> Boolean)`, but it still returns the size of the `array`, not the number of `true`:

```
val checks = arrayOf(true, false, true, true, true)

val trueCount = checks.count { true }
```

What's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Use `count { it }` instead of `count { true }`

The argument to `count` isn't a value to look for in the array; it's a predicate: a function that takes one argument and returns `true` or `false`. The predicate is called once for each item in the array, and the value (`true` or `false`) *returned* by that predicate determines whether the item is counted or not. So the result is the number of items in the array for which the predicate evaluated to `true`.

In this context, writing `{ true }` is shorthand for `{ value -> true }`, and is a constant function. It will always return `true`, regardless of what the `value` is. So *"count the number of items for which `{ true }` returns `true`"* is exactly the same as *"count the number of items"*.

What you want instead is to count the number of items where the value is `true`. The predicate you should use is `{ value -> value }`, which is a function that takes a single argument and returns the value of that argument. Since **a single lambda parameter is implicitly named `it`** when you don't give it a name, the shorthand for `{ value -> value }` is just `{ it }`.

Answer (score 16):

You're passing in a predicate that would *always* return true here:

```kotlin
val trueCount = checks.count { true }
```

And that would indeed return the size of the array. I'd expect your code to be:

```kotlin
val trueCount = checks.count { it }
```

In other words, the count of items for which "with the item called `it`, the expression `it` returns true".

An alternative you *might* find easier to read that explicitly checks for equality:

```kotlin
val trueCount = checks.count { it == true }
```

Personally I tend to avoid comparisons against Boolean literals, but I can see how it's at least *arguably* clearer in this case.

Comment: It might help to consider `checks.count { it == true }`: that clearly counts what you want, but has the same effect as the more concise `checks.count { it }`.

Comment: @gidds: Yup, will add that as an option.

Comment: Ta.  Though I wasn't suggesting people _use_ that — merely that it might help to explain the shorter version if its operation wasn't obvious.